# Flagged questions aren't showing up in my flagging summary

Tags: support, flagging

I'm noticing this more recently where flagging off-topic questions aren't being listed in my flagging summary. Consequently, my flag weight is also not updated -- it remains stagnant regardless of how many illegitimate questions I flag.

Is this a recent change to Code Review I'm not aware of or due to something else?

Comment: I _think_ they don't show up when the questions get deleted. If they got deleted by the op before a mod sees your flag, the flag goes away.

Answer (score 2):

Once I've noticed the same with "Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/..." or similar flag message.
Maybe it's a feature, since in this case users could use the *close* function. Unfortunately there are only 50 500+ rep users, so flagging is more effective than close votes.